# Navigation action/destination cannot be found from the current destination NavGraph

Tags: android, kotlin, crash, android-jetpack-navigation

Using latest Navigation component libraries 2.5.3.

I am encountering the classic crash
`Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException Navigation action/destination **:id/action_fragment_1_to_fragment_2 cannot be found from the current destination NavGraph(*:id/nav_graph) startDestination={Destination(*:id/fragment_1) class=*.Fragment1}`

I can't recreate this locally, but it is coming through semi-regularly on our crash logs.

What I find odd about this as the current destination is the nav graph itself? If it was a wrong start destination issue I would expect the read `current destination Destination(**:id/fragment_*)`

Comment: I've encountered the same exception in some crash logs and am on the same Navigation component library 2.5.3. Were you able to find a resolution to this?